# Problems getting Iron Router to work on my project

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to create a quiz app on Meteor and have had trouble setting up Iron Router forever. I'll try to give a visual:

This is the front page:
[Image 1](https://i.gyazo.com/ac1134061bc9f8f18d5e8668ccef2bef.png)

When a user clicks on the button shown above, I want the first question to show up, whose contents are filled from MongoDB.

[Image 2](https://i.gyazo.com/31d8316cdc00ee2f95a1f381f8ab973d.png)

This is what my router looks like ("question" is the name of the question template, as seen in image 2):

```
Router.route("/quiz/:_id", {
  name: "question",
  data: function(){
        return Quiz.findOne(this.params._id);}

});
```

Now, in order for me to get from image 1 to image 2, I have to use a mongo object *_id* in the html file.

```
<template name="main">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>
      Welcome to Simple Meteor Quiz app!
    </h2>
    <p>
      To try it out, simply click "start" below!
    </p>
    <p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="/quiz/cieLkdzvGZPwrnZYE">Start</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

When I click "Next Question" on image 2 to go onto the 2nd question, it doesn't work. I don't know how to make this process dynamic.

The way it looks to me right now is that I physically have to create a new route for every single question, which would look really ugly really quickly.

Any way to help implement Iron Router in this scenario? I read Discover Meteor and thought I fully understood how Iron Router works, but the more I try to fix this, the more I get confused.

**Edit:**

To solve my dilemma, I simple created a helper function which I could place behind the `/quiz/` in the main template to lead me to the quiz question, based on a suggestion by Michel Floyd.

So the helper ends up looking like this:

```
Template.main.helpers({
  nextQuestion: function(){
    queue = Quiz.find().fetch();
    return queue[0]._id;
  }
});
```

Then attached to the URL like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="/quiz/{{nextQuestion}}">Start</a>
```

Basically just spit out the first _id of first item in the array by making the collection an array via find().fetch(). Will probably randomize the _id at a later time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a way for each template to know what the next question is. For example you can add a `nextQuestionId` key to your Quiz object. Then your template can be:

```
<template name="main">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>
      Welcome to Simple Meteor Quiz app!
    </h2>
    <p>
      To try it out, simply click "start" below!
    </p>
    <p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="/quiz/{{nextQuestionId}}">
        Start
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'm going to try and create a helper function to do just that.

Comment: A helper function would be a good alternative as well. You just have to get that information from somewhere!

Comment: So I simply created an array variable inside the helper with Collection.find().fetch() and returned the first item of the array via variable[0]._id to spit out the id. Now the link works. Going to randomize it later on.